# Leaflet: using RaphaelLayer for Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, raphael, layer, leaflet

I am trying to add Raphael JS to my project which mainly consists of a map application done with Leaflet JS.

There exists a Leaflet plugin called RaphaelLayer, which can be found here:
https://github.com/dynmeth/RaphaelLayer

But I can't for the life of me figure out how to exactly use this layer plugin... There is no documentation or demo on the project page and Google gave me nothing.

Does anyone have even the slightest experience using Raphael and Leaflet together, preferably using the above plugin?

Comment: To be fair, there is a working example in the debug folder, and it says as much on the page you refer to. It looks quite nice too. A good find.

Comment: Well yes. But to use even the slightly more advanced features (FeatureGroups for example) required me to actually enter the plugin code and fix some bugs. Also as soon as a single Raphael element was added all the existing polylines are no longer correctly translated/panned.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Still, I wasn't aware of this plugin, so thanks for bringing it to my attention. Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: No problem. It really would be sweet to have Leaflet and Raphael working nicely together... If I was better at JavaScript I might even consider putting some work into that plugin...

Answer (score 0):

I found this page: http://dynmeth.github.io/RaphaelLayer/

But there isn't more documentation..